# pointwise limit of uniformly bounded sequence in $A(\mathbb T)$ is again in $A(\mathbb T)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mathbb T$ be a circle group, and $\hat{f}(n)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt;$ $(n\in \mathbb Z, f\in L^{1} (\mathbb T)).$
Put $A(\mathbb T)= \{f\in C(\mathbb T): \hat{f}\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z), \  \text{that is}, \  \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty \}. $
$A(\mathbb T)$ is normed by 
$$\|f\|=\|f\|_{A(\mathbb T)}= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)|; (f\in A(\mathbb T)).$$
Suppose $f_{n} \in A(\mathbb T), \ \|f_{n}\|\leq M,$ (Fix, $M>0$)
$$f(y)= \lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n} (y), (y\in \mathbb T)$$
and $f$ is continuous.

> **My Question is**: Can we expect,  $f\in A(\mathbb T)$ and $\|f\|\leq M$ ?

(If answer is positive, and proof is long, proper reference also will be o.k for me;)

Comment: By dominated convergence, $\hat f_n$ converges pointwise to $\hat f$.  The claim then follows from Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @prof.TT; thanks a lot; but would you please tell me; (If I understood correctly, for applying dominated convergence; put, $g_{n}(t)=f_{n}(t)e^{-ikt}, t\in \mathbb T$ fix $k\in \mathbb Z$, and we need to find, $h\in L^{1} (\mathbb T)$ such that $|g_{n}(t)| \leq h(t)$; my question is, how should I take $h$ ?; or am I missing something completely ?; ) Thanks a lot;

Comment: @DivyangBhimani $|g_n(t)| \leq M$ for all $n$ and all $t$.

Comment: @YC; thanks; would you please tell me, how it follows ?

Comment: Oh!  I guess; $f_{n}(t)= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \hat{f_{n} (k)} e^{-ikt};$ as $f_{n}\in A(\mathbb T).$ so it gives; or am I missing something ? thanks

Comment: @DivyangBhimani I think that your sub-questions really belong as questions on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: In fact, I've just noticed that this question was cross-posted on MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775600/ In future, please don't post simultaneously on both sites, or at least add a link on each version to the other version.